# Symfony Form with Sub Form and OneToMany Relationship

Tags: php, symfony

A Topic Entity exists which can have many Comment Entities, One To Many.

When creating the Form TopicType the Form CommentType is embedded:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('comments', CommentType::class)
    ;
}
```

Symfony renders this form correctly with an input box for title and the input boxes for Comment (e.g. message).

When the form is submitted an error occurs:

```
Neither the property "messages" nor one of the methods 
"addMessag()"/"removeMessag()", "addMessage()"/"removeMessage()", 
"setMessages()", "messages()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have 
public access in class "Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Topic".
```

What is the correct way to embed the Comment Form in the Topic Form?  The user will only ever be able to add one Comment when creating a Topic.

Should `CollectionType` be used?  This results in a 0 being render as a form label before the Comment is displayed. (0 being the first index of new Comment() attached to Thread).

```
 ->add('messages', CollectionType::class)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a `CollectionType::class`, and then you will need a little javascript to be able to add multiple comment from the same form. The doc explains how to do it.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Just to clarify; when creating a new Topic Entity for the form to manage, `addComment(new Comment())` should be called on Topic so that the Topic form is rendered with the Comment form?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done it in a while, but I think you need to add a comment so the Comment form is rendered in the Topic form. Not sure though